# Count number of ROWS inside each COLUMN? package XLRD

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

I started working with XLRD package for python 3.7.

I have a excel file that contains a fixed number of columns (20) but inside each column, the number of rows is changing (e.g.: first column has 21 rows, second column has 14 rows).

I wrote this:

```
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    rows_number= worksheet.nrows
    print(rows_number)
```

I'd like to know the number of rows for each column. With this code, I get 20 times (number of columns) the number of rows inside the first column. Actually I understand why. I'm iterating the `nrows` without changing the column.
How to get number of rows for all the columns?
If I try as follow, I get `AttributeError` since col doesn't have nrows attribute.

```
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    rows_number= col.nrows
    print(rows_number)
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the non empty cells in a column, using [col](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col) method in xlrd and comparing the [Cell Type](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell) and then calculating its length

```
for colx in range(worksheet.ncols):
    non_emptycells=[i for i,x in enumerate(sheet.col(colx)) if x.ctype is not 0]
    print(len(non_emptycells))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested while loop to work out the number of rows in each column

```
    for c in range(worksheet.ncols):

        counter = 0  # count of the rows
        value = worksheet.cell(row=counter, col=c).value
        while value != EMPTY:
            counter += 1
            row += 1
```

Replace the word EMPTY with a test to see if the cell is empty or not. You could then store this info in a dictionary for example once the while loop is done.